# Null Values in DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to make a VERY simple PHP form that posts a form to MySQL Database, however I am having some issues, and would welcome a simple fix for this if possible:

My PHP:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("serveraddress","db","password","dbname");
// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (email, type, cats)
VALUES
('$_POST[email]','$_POST[type]','$_POST[cats]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

My HTML:

```
<form action="personuploader.php" method="post">

        <table class="#"> 

            <tr>

                <th colspan="2">Test</th>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td>Email Address:</td>

                <td><input type="text" name="email"> </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td>Type:</td>

                <td><input type="text" name="type"> </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td>Cats:</td>

                <td><input type="text" name="cats"> </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td></td>

                <td><input type="submit" value="upload" name="upload">

            </tr>

        </table>  

    </form>
```

My SQL Configuration:

[image: SQL]

Even though I have not null set in the DB I am getting empty results, is it possible to stop the form resubmitting on refresh causing null results be entered into the DB. I will enter some form validation to stop null results passing into the post script in the future but refreshing the page still sends over null results.

Comment: To avoid re-submissions causing a NULL entry, you can always use a header to redirect to another page, or use AJAX. However, am sure there are other ways of doing this in the query itself, I just don't remember how right now. I.e.: In place of where you have `echo "1 record added";` you can do `header("Location: added.php"); exit();` --- You can also use a conditional statement `if(empty($_POST['variable'])){ die("Fill this in.");}`

Comment: Food for thought: Don't use this method `VALUES
('$_POST[email]','$_POST[type]','$_POST[cats]')` you're open to [**SQL injection**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: On a relational database (unless it's Oracle) an empty string is NOT THE SAME THING as NULL

Answer (score 1):

### Edit:

Your column names have mixed-case letters (`Cats` and `cats` are not the same)

I edited my answer, where I changed it from:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `Persons` (`email`, `type`, `cats`)
```

to

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `Persons` (`Email`, `Type`, `Cats`)
```

I also made a mistake with a missing `)` for `if(empty($_POST['email']` which has been fixed.

**Please make sure also**, that your column names are indeed called `Email` `Type` `Cats` and not `email` `type` `cats` Change it to the letter-case that is in your DB.

Your table's original structure: ([larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbPhw.png))
[image]

- **You should have talked to me first**, instead of [posting a new question with my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970879/insert-to-db-with-php)

---

**See the rest below in the code.**

---

As I stated in my comments under your original question, have put this together for you.

- Don't use this method `VALUES ('$_POST[email]','$_POST[type]','$_POST[cats]')` you're open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
- To avoid re-submissions causing an empty entry, you can use a [`header()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to redirect to another page, or use [**AJAX**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))

However, I am sure there are other ways of doing this in the query itself, I just don't remember how right now.

I.e.: In place of where you have `echo "1 record added";`

you can do `header("Location: added.php"); exit();`

You can also use a conditional statement:

```
if(empty($_POST['variable'])){ die("Fill this in.");}
```

**Try the following.** It will check for empty fields, as well as check if the `upload` submit-type button is set.

Plus, I modified the way your query was done, replacing POST variables with [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("serveraddress","db","password","dbname");
// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isset($_POST['upload'])){

// You can replace the || with && if required
// depending on what you want to check for.
    if(empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['type']) || empty($_POST['cats']))
    {
    die("You need to fill in all the fields.");
    }

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$type = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['type']);
$cats = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['cats']);

$sql="INSERT INTO `Persons` (`Email`, `Type`, `Cats`) 
VALUES ('$email','$type','$cats')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    
// Uncomment out if you're going to use echo, but not with header.
// echo "1 record added";

header("Location: redirect_to_other_page.php");
exit();

} // end of if(isset($_POST['upload']

// else conditional statement for if(isset($_POST['upload']
else{ echo "You cannot do this operation from here."; }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

---

**Footnotes:**

Just saying, the following:

```
('$_POST[email]','$_POST[type]','$_POST[cats]')
```

should have been:

```
('$_POST['email']','$_POST['type']','$_POST['cats']')
```

However, using this method is **highly discouraged**, as I already mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for this, when I post from my form to this page "personuploader.php" using your PHP script and I am getting no results passed through to the Personuploader using my form as above, no errors  and this doesntt work: header("Location: redirect_to_other_page.php");
exit();

Comment: I like your solution, but Any idea's to get it work?

Comment: I think I know what's wrong. Your column names have upper case letters (Cats and cats are not the same) I edited my answer, where I changed it from `$sql="INSERT INTO `Persons` (`email`, `type`, `cats`)` to `$sql="INSERT INTO `Persons` (`Email`, `Type`, `Cats`)` @Dan

Comment: And the `header("Location: redirect_to_other_page.php")` you need to create a page called `redirect_to_other_page.php` and put a thank you message of sorts. @Dan it will work once the DB is successfully updated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if a submit actually occured:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'POST') {
    ... submit occured, do DB stuff
}
```

And note that an empty string is NOT the same as an SQL `null`. Empty string is just that - a string which happens to be empty/zero-length. An SQL `null` is quite literally "unknown". Your code cannot insert an actual null - it can only ever insert empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether the Upload button has been clicked on the "personuploader.php" file.

```
// Initializing Variables
$email = '';
$type  = '';
$error = false;    

if ( isset ( $_POST['upload'] ) ) {

    // Then capture the POST Variables
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    // Do Some Validations
    if ($email == '') {
        $error = true;
    }

    // Process the Form if NO Errors

    if ($error == false) {

        // Insert The Data into DB
    }

}
```